# List of procedures

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to create a list of procedures, but when I use this

```
Characters=[Percy(),Annabeth(),Leo(),Chuck(),Sarah()]
```

each of these procedures brings up a tkinter window with a quote from that character, but if I run the code, instead of treating it like a list, python executes each procedure in order, am I doing this completely wrong? Or is there just no way to create a list of procedures.
Note: It needs to be in a list because I need to be able to access a random position in it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you probably want:

```
Characters = [Percy, Annabeth, Leo, Chuck, Sarah]
```

Now to call `Percy`, you do:

```
percy_result = Characters[0]()
```

As you have it, you're storing a list of *results* of those procedures instead of storing the procedures themselves.